# Weblogic 10.3.6 javascript MIME type issue in chrome

Tags: ckeditor, weblogic-10.x

Hi I am using the chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) in Mac.
When I try to load the ck editor in chrome I am getting the following error:

`Refused to execute script from 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

It is working fine in firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works however it must be put in the file as
key=value
key=value

ex:

```
XML=text/xml
js=text/javascript
```

More info for configuration: https://www.techpaste.com/2014/06/steps-configure-mime-types-weblogic-11g/

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with web logic server. Server not setting any mime type in the response when browser request the creditor.js .To resolve this issue create a file with name mimemappings.properties in config directory of your server.
Place the following content in the file

XML = text/xml 
    js = text/javascript